# PHP: How to access the last element in a XML file

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I  have an XML file that I want to be able to access the last element in the file. (NOTE: the file is dynamically updated and the latest values are always in the latest element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<tran>
    <balance>25000</balance>
    <amount>560</amount>

</tran>

<tran>
    <amount>5999</amount>
    <balance>30999</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>5000</amount>
    <balance>20000</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>8923</amount>
    <balance>25000</balance>
</tran>
```

I want to be able to access that last  node.

How can I do this using Php Simple XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your XML needs a parent node (in the example below I've inserted 'trans' element)
Then try this xpath:

```
<?php
$xmlstr=<<<EOXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<trans>
<tran>
    <balance>25000</balance>
    <amount>560</amount>

</tran>

<tran>
    <amount>5999</amount>
    <balance>30999</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>5000</amount>
    <balance>20000</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>8923</amount>
    <balance>25000</balance>
</tran>
</trans>
EOXML;

$xml =new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$last = $xml->xpath("/trans/tran[last()]");
var_dump($last);

?>
```

Comment: This worked! But how do I echo out the "balance"? (I am a Novice).
I tried $last["balance"] but it didn't work.

Comment: `$last = $xml->xpath("/trans/tran[last()]/balance");
var_dump((int)$last[0]);`

Comment: xpath is the swiss army knife for navigating your way around XML.  for more info go to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Comment: Thanks again man but when I use that `$last = $xml->xpath("/trans/tran[last()]/balance"); var_dump((int)$last[0]);` I get this `int(2147483647)` but i only want the values and when I take off the (int) i get this `object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(11) "25098976600" } `.

Comment: the (int) is a byproduct of the var_dump command.  It is just var_dump telling you that you are looking at an integer. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)  BTW: You need to know what your requirements are for the field. So if the balance could be floating point use:  $bal=(float)$last[0];  echo $bal;

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
    $xmlstr = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <transactions>
        <tran>
            <balance>25000</balance>
            <amount>560</amount>
        </tran>
        <tran>
            <amount>5999</amount>
            <balance>30999</balance>
        </tran>
        <tran>
            <amount>5000</amount>
            <balance>20000</balance>
        </tran>
        <tran>
            <amount>8923</amount>
            <balance>25000</balance>
        </tran>
    </transactions>
    XML;

    $elements = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    $last_element = $elements->tran[count($elements)-1];

    print_r($last_element);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [amount] => 8923
    [balance] => 25000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<tran>
    <balance>25000</balance>
    <amount>560</amount>
</tran>

<tran>
    <amount>5999</amount>
    <balance>30999</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>5000</amount>
    <balance>20000</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
    <amount>8923</amount>
    <balance>25000</balance>
</tran>

</doc>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$var = end($xml);
$var = end($var);
var_dump($var);
```

Output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  public 'amount' => string '8923' (length=4)
  public 'balance' => string '25000' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count "tran" elements

```
//value of $i is the total count of tran element in xml
$last_element_amount  = $xml->tran[$i]['amount'];
$last_element_balance  = $xml->tran[$i]['balance'];
```