# skip 2 element in xml code with php

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML data:

```
<root>
 <child>child1</child>
 <child>child2</child>
 <child>child3</child>
</root>
```

I can parse it with PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

I want to skip the first 2 children and get this result:

```
<root>
 <child>child3</child>
</root>
```

Thank you

Comment: how did you create `xml` in php?

Comment: Have you tried parsers yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: i load this with $xml = simplexml_load_string(url here);

Comment: and after i use foreach

Comment: do you allways want to get the last child?

Comment: Could you use XPath selectors?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the element you're interested in with an Xpath query:

```
$xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$last = $xml->xpath("child[last()]")[0];
```

Inspired by [*PHP: How to access the last element in a XML file*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099286/php-how-to-access-the-last-element-in-a-xml-file).

Answer (score 1):

If you ask in your question about removing all `<child>` elements until there is only one left, you can do that with a simple [`while`-loop](http://php.net/while):

```
<?php
/**
 * skip 2 element in xml code with php
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/q/31879798/367456
 */
$string = <<<XML
<root>
 <child>child1</child>
 <child>child2</child>
 <child>child3</child>
</root>
XML;

$xml   = simplexml_load_string($string);

$child = $xml->child;

while ($child->count() > 1) {
    unset($child[0]);
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

The output is (also: [online-demo](https://eval.in/413837)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>


 <child>child3</child>
</root>
```

if you're only concerned to get the last element, use an xpath query as it has been [suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880190/367456). Do not even consider to use the array mish-mash of json encode decode - will only break the data you need to retain in the end.